# Google App Engine Throws this error from datetime module

Tags: google-app-engine

```
  File "C:\Users\Savion\Documents\GitHub\petition-app\models\petition.py", line 55, in get_in_effect_petitions
return Petition.gql('WHERE date_added >= :1', datetime.now() - timedelta(14))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'
```

I tried to run a petition site and Google App Engine throws the above error. The module in question is clearly datetime module. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Try `datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: Thank you!! This was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completion and having a valid answer on the question, copying [Brent Washburne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584846/brent-washburne)'s comment into an answer :

```
 datetime.datetime.now()
```

should work